# Is the Argument Principle reducible to this simpler form?

Tags: integration, contour-integration

The [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) says that for a meromorphic function $f(z)$, and a closed contour $C$, $\int_{C} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz=2 \pi i(Z-P)$, with $Z$ the number of roots in $C$, and $P$ the number of poles in $C$. Assume $C$ is written in polar form as $C_p(\theta)$, $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$, so the integral at this point is $= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{f'(C_p(\theta))}{f(C_p(\theta))} \, C_p'(\theta) \, d\theta$.

Due to the fact that $\int \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz=\ln(f(z))$ and using the rule of integration by substitution, is it true that the integral can be reduced to $\ln(f(C_p(2 \pi)))-\ln(f(C_p(0)))$ (+ some constant)?

Comment: Only if the curve lies in a branch of the logarithm.

Comment: @copper.hat Which is when...?

Comment: Well, if $f(C)$ lies in a branch of the $\log$ then $\int_C {f' \over f} = 0$. You can put the argument on a solid footing by choosing a various $\log$ branches as one traverses the curve $f \circ C$. This is where the term argument principle comes from.

Comment: Presumably the $dC_p(\theta)\,d\theta$ in your integral was intended to be either just $dC_p(\theta)$ or $\frac{dC_p(\theta)}{d\theta}\,d\theta$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I fixed that now.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm still kind of confused. Are you saying for different parts of the contour, I choose different $\log$ branches? How would I know which one to pick?

Comment: @copper.hat Update: So, are you saying that the whole integral would be made of sums of $\left(f(C_p(\theta_{1})) - f(C_p(\theta_{2})) \right)$ with $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}$ chosen at sections of $[0, 2 \pi]$ with different sections using different $\ln$ branch cuts?

Comment: @DUO Yes. See for example, the commentary after [Theorem] 3.4 Argument Principle in Conway's "Functions of one complex variable". Basicaly a branch of $\log f$ can be defined on a collection of disks that cover $C$.

Comment: @copper.hat Which page would that be on?

Comment: P.124 in the 2nd Ed.

Answer (score 1):

A comment that got too long:

I think that you are missing the essence of the argument principle here - for any continuous function $f$ that is (finite and) non zero on a simple curve $\gamma$, one can define a continuous logarithm of $f$ on the curve with the usual properties so for example if the curve is closed and parametrized say by $\gamma(t), t \in [0,1]$, $f(\gamma (t))=e^{\alpha(t)}, \alpha$ continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\alpha(1)-\alpha(0)=2\pi in(f)$ for some integer (called the degree of $f$ wr $\gamma$ or equivalently $2\pi in$ is called the argument change of $f$ when it goes around $\gamma$) that depends only on $f$ but not on the parametrization of the curve.

In particular the integral in the OP can always be computed as a difference of logarithms when the function $f$ is just real differentiable on $\gamma$ rectifiable (so in other words we need only $t \to f(\gamma(t))$ differentiable in $t \in [0,1]$ and some similar smoothness condition on $\gamma$) as then we can construct $\alpha$ differentiable and $f'd\gamma/f=\alpha'(t)dt$

The point of the argument principle in the usual complex analysis setting of holomorphic/meromorphic functions is that there is a simple way to compute $n(f)$ in terms of the orders of zeroes and poles of $f$ inside $\gamma$ as long as $\gamma$ is a rectifiable Jordan curve and $f$ is meromorphic inside $\gamma$ and continuous non-zero finite on $\gamma$; this seems "obvious" but simple examples of harmonic (hence quite smooth) functions with for example a simple zero at the origin in the unit disc and no other zeroes, but of zero degree, so the integral is zero shows the power of the classical result

(eg $2\Re z+iz^2$ is harmonic and has an isolated zero at the origin of "multiplicity" zero and no other zeroes inside the closed unit disc, so its argument doesn't change when going around by 360 degrees on the unit circle as one can show that $2\Re z+iz^2$ avoids the positive imaginary axis when $|z|<1$)

Comment: So are you saying that the argument principle is used more for using zeros and poles to find the winding number, rather than the other way around?

Comment: I would say that in general, the answer is yes, one uses zeroes/poles to compute integrals (eg the method of residues); the one caveat is that for a holomorphic function the order of the zeroes is always a positive number so for example if one shows that the integral in question is less than say $2 \pi$ in absolute value, that implies no zeroes etc so there are theoretical problems where we go the other way but using essentially that the order of the zeroes are positive integers (which is specifically true for holomorphic functions but not for other classes of functions with isolated zeroes)

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that it's hard going the opposite way (the direction I want to go in)?

Comment: depends on your purpose and what functions you consider - generally determining a continuous branch of the logarithm (or equivalently of the argument) is a hard problem, computing zeroes/poles, a much easier one - in the holomorphic/meromorphic case the latter allows computation of the former and that to me is the essence of the argument principle and why it is emphaszed here; in other contexts - harmonic functions-  where it still holds, some difficult theorem use it but they still require a lot of extra preparation